# IndexError　Can int be used as indices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I got an error,
IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices    .
I am making sound recognition app.
My　code is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
import  pickle
from scipy import fft
from time import localtime, strftime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import  disk,remove_small_objects
from skimage.filter import rank
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte 
import wave

folder = 'mlsp_contest_dataset/'


essential_folder = folder+'essential_data/'
supplemental_folder = folder+'supplemental_data/'
spectro_folder =folder+'my_spectro/'
single_spectro_folder =folder+'my_spectro_single/'
dp_folder = folder+'DP/'

# Each audio file has a unique recording identifier ("rec_id"), ranging from 0 to 644. 
# The file rec_id2filename.txt indicates which wav file is associated with each rec_id.
rec2f = pd.read_csv(essential_folder + 'rec_id2filename.txt', sep = ',')

# There are 19 bird species in the dataset. species_list.txt gives each a number from 0 to 18. 
species = pd.read_csv(essential_folder + 'species_list.txt', sep = ',')
num_species = 19

# The dataset is split into training and test sets. 
# CVfolds_2.txt gives the fold for each rec_id. 0 is the training set, and 1 is the test set.
cv =  pd.read_csv(essential_folder + 'CVfolds_2.txt', sep = ',')

# This is your main label training data. For each rec_id, a set of species is listed. The format is:
# rec_id,[labels]
raw =  pd.read_csv(essential_folder + 'rec_labels_test_hidden.txt', sep = ';')
label = np.zeros(len(raw)*num_species)
label = label.reshape([len(raw),num_species])
for i in range(len(raw)):
    line = raw.iloc[i]
    labels = line[0].split(',')
    labels.pop(0) # rec_id == i
    for c in labels:
        if(c != '?'):
            print(label)
            label[i,c] = 1
```

I run this code,
I got the error in this point `label[i,c] = 1` .
I tried to see `label` variable by `print(label)`
`label` is like

```
warn(skimage_deprecation('The `skimage.filter` module has been renamed '
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ...,
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

I think,the error means integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean cannot used as array indices, but I put int in array index many time, so I cannot understand why this error happen.
Debug told me,

```
labels
```

has  labels:: ['?']    .

```
c
```

of

```
for c in labels[i]:
```

has '?',I really cannot understand ? type.I think this ? cause the error, but I do not know how to fix this.
How can I fix this?

Comment: `for c in labels: ...`, but `labels` is a list of strings. Strings are not in the set "*integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean*". (Also note: `np.zeros((len(raw),num_species))` is simpler.)

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you very much!! Which part is np.zeros((len(raw),num_species)) that u told me  ? How can i fix this?

Comment: I only noted that your two lines before the for loop can be done in one line, without having to reshape. As for your problem: I don't know what you're trying to do, but trying to use characters as numpy array indices will surely not work.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thx.I add my codes info, if u know it please help me.

Comment: The problem is not "?", the problem is that `'?'` is a string (the debugger is telling you that you have a list with a string inside). It could've been `'1'` and be equally wrong. What you're doing just doesn't make sense, and your edit didn't help clarify it a bit.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Oh,really.Would u tell me which part does not make sense?

Comment: See hpaulj's answer.

Comment: What are the values of `i` and `c`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that when indexing a numpy array

```
only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

`label` is a 2d array of floats, with current value of 0.:

```
label = np.zeros([len(raw),num_species])
```

In the loop:

```
for i in range(len(raw)):        # i=0,1,2,...
```

have you checked what `raw` is like?  Coming from `pd.read_csv` I imagine it's a dataframe; `iloc[i]` selects a row, but isn't already split into columns?

```
    line = raw.iloc[i]
    labels = line[0].split(',')
    labels.pop(0) # rec_id == i
```

what is `labels` like?  I'm guessing it's any array of strings

```
    for c in labels:
        if(c != '?'):          # evidently `c` is a string
            print(label)       # prints the 2d array
            label[i,c] = 1
```

Indexing for a 2d array should be something like `label[0,1]`.  `c` could be one of the other things in error message.  But it cannot be a string.

Dataframes do allow indexing with strings - that's a pandas feature.  But numpy arrays have to have numeric indices, or a few alternatives.  They are not indexed with strings (except in the case of structured arrays).

---

```
In [209]: label = np.zeros((3,5))
In [210]: label
Out[210]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
In [211]: label[1,3]
Out[211]: 0.0
In [212]: label[1,3]=1      # index with integers OK
In [213]: label[0,2]=1
In [214]: label[0,'?'] =1    # index with a string - ERROR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-214-3738f623c78e> in <module>()
----> 1 label[0,'?'] =1

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

In [215]: label[0,:] =2     # index with a slice
In [216]: label
Out[216]: 
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```